# Is it possible to set the "tab position" in an html doc using React

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

Assume I have this component:

[image]

```
   React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {pg: 0};
      },
      nextPage: function(){
        this.setState({ pg: this.state.pg+1} )
      },
      render: function() {
        var inputs = [ <input key={1} placeholder="one"/>, 
                       <input key={2} placeholder="two"/>, 
                       <input key={3} placeholder="three"/>]
        if(this.state.pg === 1){
          inputs = [ <input key={4} placeholder="four"/>, 
                     <input key={5} placeholder="five"/>, 
                     <input key={6} placeholder="six"/>]
        }
        return(
          <div>
              <h1>start here</h1>
              {inputs}
              <button onClick={this.nextPage.bind(this)}>next</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/75909/

I am aiming for a very easy workflow. Inputs placed one after another can be edited without needing a mouse. The process would go like this

- Click "start here" to set the "tab position"
- hit tab
- enter a value, hit tab
- enter a value, hit tab
- enter a value, hit tab
- hit enter

However when I change to next page, I need to manually click "start here" in order to be able to do this again.

Is there anyway I can automatically move the tab position to "start here"? (I don't want to focus on the first input element until the user hits Tab)

Comment: Have you tried just adding a [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) property?

Comment: all you need to do is do a `document.addEventListener('keypress', handler)` and then in the handler function` if(e.keyCode === 9) {first input.focus()}`

Comment: @lonewarrior556 [here is a fiddle doing what you describe](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/75911/)

Comment: @john-ruddell want to put that in an answer?

Comment: @lonewarrior556 sure thing! just made it an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment and the OP's request to make it an answer. What you want to do is have a listener for the tab key and programatically focus the input when tab is pressed. the trick is you remove the listener after applying the focus so that it will naturally focus the next input.

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { pg: 0 };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyPress)
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyPress)
    },
    handleKeyPress: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.keyCode === 9) {
            this.refs.firstInput && this.refs.firstInput.focus();
            window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyPress)
        }
    },
    nextPage: function () {
        this.setState({ pg: this.state.pg + 1 }, function () {
            window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyPress)
        })
    },
    render: function () {
        var inputs = [<input key={1} ref="firstInput" placeholder="one" />,
        <input key={2} placeholder="two" />,
        <input key={3} placeholder="three" />]
        if (this.state.pg === 1) {
            inputs = [<input key={4} ref="firstInput" placeholder="four" />,
            <input key={5} placeholder="five" />,
            <input key={6} placeholder="six" />]
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> start here</h1>
                {inputs}
                <button onClick={this.nextPage}>next</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy solution would be adding an autoFocus on the input like so:

```
if(this.state.pg === 1){
        inputs = [ <input key={4} placeholder="four" autoFocus />, 
                     <input key={5} placeholder="five"/>, 
                     <input key={6} placeholder="six"/>]
        }
```

Comment: I don't want to focus on the first editable input element until the user hits Tab

Answer (score 0):

As per the MDN docs on the html5 `<input>` element and it's autofocus prop:

> This Boolean attribute lets you specify that a form control should
>   have input focus when the page loads, unless the user overrides it
>   (e.g. by typing in a different control). Only one form element in a
>   document can have the autofocus attribute, which is a Boolean. It
>   cannot be applied if the type attribute is set to hidden (that is, you
>   cannot automatically set focus to a hidden control). Note that the
>   focusing of the control may occur before the firing of the
>   DOMContentLoaded event.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the following:

```
$(document.body).on("keyup", function (e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    $("input:visible:first").focus();
  }
});
```

Whenever a user presses tab and nothing is selected, it will autoselect the first field, continuing your pattern.

New fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/75910/